# Running CRFSuite examples

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, crfsuite

I'm trying to use CRFSuite but I can't figure out how to use the example/ner.py and pos.py

Precisely, how do I make an input of the form:

```
# Ner.py
fields = 'y w pos chk'
```

or

```
# Pos.py
fields = 'w num cap sym p1 p2 p3 p4 s1 s2 s3 s4 y'
```

The "y w pos" I can get from a CoNNL model, for example, but the "chk" part and all those fields in pos.py I don't really get.

Also, is there a way to process a raw text (without all those tags) with CRFSuite given that I have a trained model?

Comment: I, too, am interested in solving this issue; Paticularly, starting from the cited CoNLL data (2000 for chunking, 2003 for NER, but what to use for PoS?), how do I generated the PoS data. As cited, the input has to be `'w num cap sym p1 p2 p3 p4 s1 s2 s3 s4 y'`, meaning the word itself first and the PoS tag last. But what is all the stuff in between and how to get and generate it?

Comment: Maybe the question regarding the PoS part more precisely should be: How does one generate the PoS tagging input format from a regular, PoS tagged OWPL file (`"word tag\n"...`) using these scripts?

Answer (score 2):

@michele is right. This task requires another dataset. I believe the datasets are here: http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `ner.py` or `pos.py` with the data provided by the author of the tutorial. You need a proper CoNLL-2000 data set. :)

Just as an example, you can find it [here](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/conll2009-st/trial-data.html)

I hope I have replied correctly to your question.

Comment: Yes, sort of, but how to generate the CRFsuite input data for PoS tagging? I.e., where is the original data set that is used to generate training/test files using the PoS template with the fields as shown in the question? (The ner.py file shows what each field actually means (num, cap, sym, p1-4, and s1-4).)

Comment: To get  CoNLL-2000 data set (English): `import nltk;train_sents = list(nltk.corpus.conll2000.iob_sents('train.txt'));
test_sents = list(nltk.corpus.conll2000.iob_sents('test.txt'))`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it is simpler to slightly modify the `pos.py` file to do what it should be doing. Now the input format for `pos.py` is `'w y'`, while the features `'num cap sym p1 p2 p3 p4 s1 s2 s3 s4'` are all generated by the script itself. This should solve the `pos.py` issues. Here is the gist:

https://gist.github.com/fnl/21116fa57527946c5dbe

As for the `ner.py` script, as answered by @Legend already, the relevant input data format can be found, for example, here:

http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/